# Cannot Require Once When Loading CiviCRM After Drupal Upgrade

Tags: upgrade, civicrm.settings.php

I am trying to upgrade to the newest security release of Drupal 8 (8.9.14).  After completing the update (Drupal is bootstrapping because the login page works) but CiviCRM stops being able to require specific files.  The full error is:

```
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required 'DB/DataObject.php' (include_path='.:/var/www/site_name/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core:/var/www/site_name/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/packages:.:/var/www/site_name/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/:/var/www/site_name/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core//packages:/var/www/site_name/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/vendor/tecnickcom:/var/www/site_name/vendor/pear/archive_tar:/var/www/site_name/vendor/pear/auth_sasl:/var/www/site_name/vendor/pear/console_getopt:/var/www/site_name/vendor/pear/db:/var/www/site_name/vendor/pear/log:/var/www/site_name/vendor/pear/mail:/var/www/site_name/vendor/pear/mail_mime:/var/www/site_name/vendor/pear/net_smtp:/var/www/site_name/vendor/pear/net_socket:/var/www/site_name/vendor/pear/pear-core-minimal/src:/var/www/site_name/vendor/pear/pear_exception:/var/www/site_name/vendor/pear/validate_finance_creditcard:.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/site_name/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Core/DAO.php on line 26, referer: https://site.org/user/login
```

I tried adding the full relative path to the file (../../../civicrm-packages/DB/DataObject.php) and this does not stop the problem.

My CiviCRM root is,

```
$civicrm_paths['civicrm.root']['path'] = '/var/www/site_folder/vendor/civicrm/';
```

The variable is

```
$civicrm_root = '/var/www/site_folder/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/';
```

I tried changing the path for the array in ['civicrm.root']['path'] but this did not do anything.

I tried upgrading CiviCRM too. That did not work either.

I have figured out that the issue is not related to the Drupal upgrade itself but rather to the packages being upgraded with Drupal.

- symfony/debug (v4.4.20 => v4.4.22):
- symfony/var-dumper (v4.4.21 => v4.4.22):
- guzzlehttp/psr7 (1.8.1 => 1.8.2)
- doctrine/cache (1.10.2 => 1.11.0)
- doctrine/inflector (1.4.3 => 1.4.4)
- laminas/laminas-feed (2.14.0 => 2.14.1)

I have not narrowed down which library is the issue.

I appreciate any help figuring this out.

Thanks,
Josh

Comment: I think Pradeep is right that the path settings are wrong, but also since you mention the packages this sounds like maybe [composer patches hasn't been enabled](https://civicrm.org/blog/daved/action-required-drupal-8-installs-and-upgrades-composer-and-patches)

Comment: Paths are wrong : one has site_name and others have site_folder. 
Also, upgrading to Drupal 8.9.x is useless since there are punch of fixes after that,  and 8x is no longer supported.

Answer (score 0):

The `$civicrm_paths['civicrm.root']['path']` should match with $civicrm_root,

can you try by updating your `$civicrm_paths['civicrm.root']['path']` to

```
$civicrm_paths['civicrm.root']['path'] = '/var/www/networkpaao/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/';
```